# Re-Post - Ruby on Rails Script to Rename Files

Tags: ruby, rename

I have reposted this because i have added to it

I have a script that renames files from a .csv file, this file works fine but am looking to edit it a little bit more so that it help me even more.

The scenario is I have 8,000 images that have a CID code some of them have the CID code some of them have extra text with it and are multiple images under the same CID ID i.e `17263.jpg` `17263a.jpg`, `17623b.jpg`, I then need to rename the CID images with product codes to work on a website, as well as adding the relevant *a* or *b* or *c* letter after it, if there are multiple images I have the files CID files in the left hand of the .csv column but i don't have a easy way of matching the two code up together because there are so many.

I was wondering if there was a way of scripting ruby to search for the relevant cid code within the file name and rename it as the relevant product number?

Here is a link to where i downloaded the Script, i have changed it so it works with new ruby

http://roguepenguin.net/PFID2SKU/

Sorry for the mess up with the post earlier this week

Hope you can understand.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the ruby file, and I did not try to do it. I think you have two questions:

1. How to search for relevant CID code inside file name?
2. How to rename the file with the replaced name.

Here my try:

1. Finding the CID code

   - Learn how to use reg-expressions in Ruby.
   - Use the String function `match` to see if the CID matches the filename
   - Use the function `sub` to replace the CID with the new value. You then have the new filename.
2. Renaming the file

   - There is a library `fileutils` in Ruby, which you have to require.
   - then use the function `mv`

Hope that helps ...